# weird beheaviour when adding matrices

Tags: python, matrix

I just ran into this weird bug that I just wasn't able to solve.

```
b1 += l1_delta
```

when I ran this line it gave me an error:

> **ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,16) doesn't match the broadcast shape (3,16)**

after a while I thought let's just try changing it to this:

```
b1 = b1 + l1_delta
```

and for some reason this worked. Is this a weird bug in Python or is there a reason why this works? As far as I know there is no difference between `a += b` and `a = a + b`.

Comment: How are `b1` and `l1_delta` defined?

Comment: can you print b1 and l1_delta ? Depending on the type, + and += might have different behaviour, like giving you a (4,16) shape versus complaining that (1,16) doesn't match (3,16)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ValueError%3A+non-broadcastable+output+operand+with+shape